# Can massif dump log incrementally

Tags: valgrind, massif

I use the command

```
valgrind --tool=massif --threshold=1 <bin>
```

The command only generates a massif.out. file after I close the test program. Is there a way to let massif dump the file incrementally during the test program runs?

Answer (score 2):

The file produced at the end contains the status of the memory at different moments of the program run. The output file can then visualised various ways e.g. using ms_print or massif-visualizer.

These will show the evolution of the memory, and so should correspond to your request of seeing 'incremental' dumps.

You can also if you want trigger massif dump yourself during execution, typically using vgdb from a shell window. See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.monitor-commands for more information.